# Can't download flash player by terminal

Tags: flash

When I tried to install the flash player plugin I got this error message:

```
jerin@jerin-Lenovo-G50-70:~$ sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin
[sudo] password for jerin: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Please help me out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're installing another package at the same time this error will occur.

 Make sure you are not using another package manager such Synpatic or Ubuntu Software Center.

If you're not then reboot will correct this problem.